# redirect to registration page if user not signed-in in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

From reading the devise code and wiki it seems, there is no option to redirect user to registration page if a user is not logged in. In lib/devise/failure_app.rb, it appear that the redirect url is hardcoded.

```
  def redirect_url
    opts  = {}
    route = :"new_#{scope}_session_path"
    opts[:format] = request_format unless skip_format?

    if respond_to?(route)
      send(route, opts)
    else
      root_path(opts)
    end
  end
```

I want to ask that's the best practice in getting the work done. I'm thinking of manually setting user_return_to session value, then make a call to registration page. Is that a good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best practice in this situation is following this devise wiki page: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Comment: I dont understand that wiki page can you explain a little bit, I'm new to rails, I want to show login page if user is not logged in

Comment: The linked article has a different (better) link it refers you to, see here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Devise, the recommendation is to follow these instructions:

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated

To do this, define a custom failure app with a route method that returns a symbol representing the named route to redirect to:

```
# app/lib/my_failure_app.rb
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    :new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

Then inside the Devise initializer, specify your failure app:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = MyFailureApp
end
```

Load the lib directory

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```